# Info googlemaps API doesn't work with scaling website page

Tags: javascript

I'm using a googlemap API.
And it always worked fine.
But now I am scaling the page in the website with the googleapi.
And it doesn't show the info near the marker anymore.
When I remove the scaling, it works like before.
Somebody who can help me?

[The link to the script:](https://www.pctraverse.nl/Project/aangeboden/flyers/geo.js)

Answer (score 0):

In the scaling, the mouse events doesn't work.
So I had to remove the 'click' function.
And now it shows the info again.
Another option could be to make a standalone webpage.